# How can I fetch data from facebook events using graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch data from a facebook event using graph API. I wrote the following code :

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/events/1588093858105216';
$contents = file_get_contents( $url );
if( $contents )
{
    $data = json_decode( $contents, true );
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $data );
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

My event page address URL is https://www.facebook.com/events/1588093858105216/.
The above code is not working properly. When I am using the same code for a page,e.g., https://www.facebook.com/TangeloTown , it works fine.

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/TangeloTown';
$contents = file_get_contents( $url );
if( $contents )
{
    $data = json_decode( $contents, true );
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $data );
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Also, I am unable to run it on localhost. Please help me to solve this or please tell me any other method to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you need an access token to access all graph api. Please check the doc here for event api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event

In your case, if you want to access event, you need a user access token or app access token. To get user access token you check this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens in this way, you need to ask user for authorization. But if you only want to access public event, you can simply use your app access token, which can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/, but the prerequisite is that you need to register a FB app.